# how can i execute from service

Tags: c++, windows, service

i have a window service program and i need to start another executable from it ,but non  of the functions are executed in SvcMain. I searched for the solution but found somewhere written that the initialization should be completed in less than one second or else it wont execute so was the failure of my `createprocess` 
they say for this to work you need to set `SetServiceStatus` to `service_start_pending`, but i cant find any document to illustrate it. how can i do this?

Comment: If this is for Windows, and it seems to be so, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a secondary thread from SvcMain and let that thread do the job of starting external executable.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your needs. You can describe them in more details in your original questions so that people understand what exactly you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's as easy as it sounds. Before you call `CreateProcess`, create a `SERVICE_STATUS` object, set the `SERVICE_STATUS.dwCurrentState` to `SERVICE_START_PENDING`, and call `SetServiceStatus(handle_to_your_service, &the_service_status);` .

It's probably easiest to make the `SERVICE_STATUS` object a global. You'll be calling `SetServiceStatus` more than once, and most of the members will remain constant over time. E.g. `.dwServiceType` shouldn't change at all, and `.dwControlsAccepted` usually doesn't.